# How to parse a substring with missing sub string from text using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to parse out the sub strings from a string, that follow a particular format

The format of the survey responses are of the form

```
<survey_name>_<category_name>_<question_type>.<response_type>
```

ex: input strings

```
y_survey_category1_1st.no
x_survey_category2_2nd
survey_z_category_3_3rd.yes_more_7
x_survey_category_4_4th.excluded
survey_z_category5.yes_more_7
survey_z_category_6.yes_more_7
```

Here's what I have so far. It works for most cases, except the one where the question_type is optional (ex: 5 and 6 inputs above).

Here are the restrictions for each sub-part

```
 1. survey_name can only be one of the 3 values
 2. category_name will always be present and can have underscores
 3. question_type may be present and may have underscore in it
 4. response_type may be present and may have underscore in it
 5. Either question_type or response_type or both will always be present
```

```
(x_survey|y_survey|survey_z)_([\w_]+)_(1st|2nd|3rd|4th)[.]?(.*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/bGc0gM/1

Any help on how to modify the regex so that it works for all the cases?

Comment: You say that you need a _ between each, and you show examples with a dot, so ?

Comment: oops...fixed the format string in the Q. It has a dot before response_type

Comment: Please clarify what is optional in the pattern and what charachters to expect in each part.

Comment: @FredrikHedman updated the post with more details. question_type and response_type are optional but not at the same time. survey_name can only be one of the 3 possible values. Every sub-part can have underscores in them

Comment: Can there be more than one underscore in category type or question_type?

Comment: @FredrikHedman In question_type it's possible to have more than 1, but in category_type it'll be 0 or 1

Comment: Both category_name and question_type can have zero or more internal
underscores.  This results in an ambiguity, since we have no way of knowing
when category_name ends and question_type starts.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to find the regex that use the `question_type` even if it's optional, I forced the category letters/underscore and end by digit

```
category : [a-z_]+\d
all : (x_survey|y_survey|survey_z)_([a-z_]+\d)(?>_(1st|2nd|3rd|4th))?(?>\.(.*))?
```

[`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/bGc0gM/2)

Comment: This almost works, but fails for cases where category name doesn't end with a digit. There is no restriction that category_name will end by digit. can you fix that?

Comment: @user330612 just change this part, just make sure it can't end with a dash _ and it' be ok, replace \d by what can be the last thing like `[a-z\d]`

Comment: It still fails for this ```y_survey_category_1st.no```
https://regex101.com/r/bGc0gM/3

Comment: any idea why it fails for the above?

Comment: @user330612 Sorry I don't know, the syntax is tricky so I don't know how to regex it

Comment: Note that the `re` python module does not implement atomic gpups `(?> )`, so the regular expressen above results in an error: `unknown extension ?> at position 41`

Answer (score 0):

The short version with a snippet of code that shows a regex that will work. The pattern has extra spaces added so you need to set the `re.X` flag. Also set `re.I`to ignore case.

```
    # Capture:
    # <survey_name>_<category_name>_<question_type>.<response_type>
    #     (0)           (1)            (2) or (4)     (3) or (6)
    pat = r"""^(x_survey|y_survey|survey_z)    # <sn>  (0)
               _                               # _
               ([^.]+                          # <cn> (1)
       (?:                                     # One of
            _(1st|2nd|3rd|4th)  [.]([\w]+)$ |  # qt (2) & rt (3)
            _(1st|2nd|3rd|4th)            $ |  # qt (4)
        (?<!_(1st|2nd|3rd|4th)) [.]([\w]+)$    # rt (6)
       )
           """
    matcher = re.compile(pat, re.I | re.X)
```

For a longer version with two variations for a solution with test cases included:

```
"""
Format: <survey_name>_<category_name>_<question_type>.<response_type>

 1. survey_name can only be one of the 3 values
 2. category_name will always be present and can have underscores
 3. question_type may be present and may have underscore in it
 4. response_type may be present and may have underscore in it
 5. Either question_type or response_type or both will always be present

A) <survery_name> always there
    easy to find, one of three: (x_survey|y_survey|survey_z)
B) <category_name> always there
    has 0 or more internal underscores
C) <question_type> optional
    one ore more internal underscores
    ends before a dot or at end of line
    one of 4 values: (1st|2nd|3rd|4th)
D) <response_type> optional
    starts before a .
    ends at end of line

Both category_name and question_type can have zero or more internal
underscores.  This results in an ambiguity, since we have no way of knowing
when category_name ends and question_type starts.

Assume that question_type is one of the 4 values (1st|2nd|3rd|4th).  this
results in 3 valid cases and one that should not match:

Format: <survey_name>_<category_name>_<question_type>.<response_type>

0) Both question_type and response_type present
   (x_survey|y_survey|survey_z)_<category_name>_(1st|2nd|3rd|4th).<response_type>
   -->
   p1 = r"^(x_survey|y_survey|survey_z)_([^.]+)_(1st|2nd|3rd|4th)[.]([\w]+)$"  # noqa:

1) Only question_type and no response_type present
   (x_survey|y_survey|survey_z)_<category_name>_(1st|2nd|3rd|4th)
   -->
   p2 = r"^(x_survey|y_survey|survey_z)_([^.]+)_(1st|2nd|3rd|4th)$"

2) No question_type and only response_type present
   (x_survey|y_survey|survey_z)_<category_name>.<response_type>
   -->
   p3 = r"^(x_survey|y_survey|survey_z)_([^.]+)(?<!_(1st|2nd|3rd|4th))[.]([\w]+)$"  # noqa:

3) Neither question_type nor response_type present
   (x_survey|y_survey|survey_z)_<category_name>

   Neither of p1, p2 nor p3 will match.

Since the patterns are mutually exclusive we can try them one after the other.
We could also combine them into one pattern.

We can combine the three patterns in one large pattern or we can try them one
after the other.

"""
from collections import namedtuple
import re

Response = namedtuple('Response', ['survey_name',
                                   'category_name',
                                   'question_type',
                                   'response_type'])

cases = ["survey_z__CATEGORY",
         "y_survey_category1_1st.no",
         "x_survey_category2_2nd",
         "survey_z_category_3_3rd.yes_more_7",
         "x_survey_category_4_4th.excluded",
         "X_SURVEY_CATEGORY_4_4TH.excluded",
         "survey_z_category5.yes_more_7",
         "survey_z_category_6.yes_more_7",
         "survey_z_category_7._yes_more_77",
         "survey_z_category_8_._yes_more_88",
         "survey_z_category_8888__foo._yes_more_77_",
         "survey_z_category_22_22_1st_2nd._yes_more_77_",
         "survey_z__CATEGORY_2222_1ST__2ND._yes_odd_77_",
         "survey_z__CATEGORY_3333_1ST__2ND",
         "survey_z__CATEGORY_foo_1ST__2ND._yes_odd_77_",
         ]


def parse_survey_response_1(line):
    """Parse a line with a survey response seting optional values not

    present to None.  Return a Response or None when no match.

    Use a list of mutually exclusive patterns for line format:
    <survey_name>_<category_name>_<question_type>.<response_type>
    """
    # Format <sn>_<cn>_(1st|2nd|3rd|4th).<rt>
    # Format <sn>_<cn>_(1st|2nd|3rd|4th)
    # Format: <sn>_<cn>.<rt>
    prfx = r"^(x_survey|y_survey|survey_z)_([^.]+)"
    regexs = [
        prfx + r"_(1st|2nd|3rd|4th)[.]([\w]+)$",       # 4 captures
        prfx + r"_(1st|2nd|3rd|4th)($)",               # 3+1 captures
        prfx + r"(?<!_(1st|2nd|3rd|4th))[.]([\w]+)$",  # 4 captures
        ]
    matchers = [re.compile(r, re.I | re.X) for r in regexs]

    for m in matchers:
        parsed_line = m.search(line)
        if parsed_line:
            map_empty2none = (g if g else None for g in parsed_line.groups())
            return Response._make(map_empty2none)
    return None


def parse_survey_response_2(line):
    """Parse a line with a survey response seting optional values not

    present to None.  Return a Response or None when no match.

    Use a one large pattern for line format:
    <survey_name>_<category_name>_<question_type>.<response_type>
    """
    # Capture:
    # <survey_name>_<category_name>_<question_type>.<response_type>
    #     (0)           (1)            (2) or (4)     (3) or (6)
    pat = r"""^(x_survey|y_survey|survey_z)    # <sn>  (0)
               _                               # _
               ([^.]+)                         # <cn> (1)
       (?:                                     # One of
            _(1st|2nd|3rd|4th)  [.]([\w]+)$ |  # qt (2) & rt (3)
            _(1st|2nd|3rd|4th)            $ |  # qt (4)
        (?<!_(1st|2nd|3rd|4th)) [.]([\w]+)$    # rt (6)
       )
           """

    matcher = re.compile(pat, re.I | re.X)
    parsed_line = matcher.search(line)
    if parsed_line:
        pg = list(parsed_line.groups())
        pg[2] = pg[2] if pg[2] else pg[4]  # capture 2 or 4
        pg[3] = pg[3] if pg[3] else pg[6]  # capture 3 or 6
        return Response._make(pg[:4])
    return None


def unparse_survey(response):
    if response.response_type:
        head = '_'.join(e for e in response[:-1] if e)
        unparsed = '.'.join([head, response.response_type])
    else:
        unparsed = '_'.join(e for e in response if e)
    return unparsed


for c in cases:
    p1 = parse_survey_response_1(c)
    p2 = parse_survey_response_2(c)
    print(c)
    print(p1)
    print(p2)
    print(20*'=')
    if p1 or p2:
        assert(c == unparse_survey(p1))
        assert(c == unparse_survey(p2))
```

Running gives:

```
run reex02.py                                                                                                                                       
survey_z__CATEGORY
None
None
====================
y_survey_category1_1st.no
Response(survey_name='y_survey', category_name='category1', question_type='1st', response_type='no')
Response(survey_name='y_survey', category_name='category1', question_type='1st', response_type='no')
====================
x_survey_category2_2nd
Response(survey_name='x_survey', category_name='category2', question_type='2nd', response_type=None)
Response(survey_name='x_survey', category_name='category2', question_type='2nd', response_type=None)
====================
survey_z_category_3_3rd.yes_more_7
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='category_3', question_type='3rd', response_type='yes_more_7')
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='category_3', question_type='3rd', response_type='yes_more_7')
====================
x_survey_category_4_4th.excluded
Response(survey_name='x_survey', category_name='category_4', question_type='4th', response_type='excluded')
Response(survey_name='x_survey', category_name='category_4', question_type='4th', response_type='excluded')
====================
X_SURVEY_CATEGORY_4_4TH.excluded
Response(survey_name='X_SURVEY', category_name='CATEGORY_4', question_type='4TH', response_type='excluded')
Response(survey_name='X_SURVEY', category_name='CATEGORY_4', question_type='4TH', response_type='excluded')
====================
survey_z_category5.yes_more_7
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='category5', question_type=None, response_type='yes_more_7')
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='category5', question_type=None, response_type='yes_more_7')
====================
survey_z_category_6.yes_more_7
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='category_6', question_type=None, response_type='yes_more_7')
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='category_6', question_type=None, response_type='yes_more_7')
====================
survey_z_category_7._yes_more_77
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='category_7', question_type=None, response_type='_yes_more_77')
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='category_7', question_type=None, response_type='_yes_more_77')
====================
survey_z_category_8_._yes_more_88
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='category_8_', question_type=None, response_type='_yes_more_88')
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='category_8_', question_type=None, response_type='_yes_more_88')
====================
survey_z_category_8888__foo._yes_more_77_
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='category_8888__foo', question_type=None, response_type='_yes_more_77_')
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='category_8888__foo', question_type=None, response_type='_yes_more_77_')
====================
survey_z_category_22_22_1st_2nd._yes_more_77_
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='category_22_22_1st', question_type='2nd', response_type='_yes_more_77_')
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='category_22_22_1st', question_type='2nd', response_type='_yes_more_77_')
====================
survey_z__CATEGORY_2222_1ST__2ND._yes_odd_77_
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='_CATEGORY_2222_1ST_', question_type='2ND', response_type='_yes_odd_77_')
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='_CATEGORY_2222_1ST_', question_type='2ND', response_type='_yes_odd_77_')
====================
survey_z__CATEGORY_3333_1ST__2ND
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='_CATEGORY_3333_1ST_', question_type='2ND', response_type=None)
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='_CATEGORY_3333_1ST_', question_type='2ND', response_type=None)
====================
survey_z__CATEGORY_foo_1ST__2ND._yes_odd_77_
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='_CATEGORY_foo_1ST_', question_type='2ND', response_type='_yes_odd_77_')
Response(survey_name='survey_z', category_name='_CATEGORY_foo_1ST_', question_type='2ND', response_type='_yes_odd_77_')
====================
```